# Two inequalities along the proof of nondifferentiability of Brownian motion: why do they hold true?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-explanation, brownian-motion, limsup-and-liminf

I quote **Mörters/Peres (2010)**.

First, consider the following result contained [here in Lemma 1.1 (p.2)](https://www.math-berlin.de/images/stories/lecnotes_moerters.pdf)  (*Scaling invariance property of Brownian motion*). Then

> For a function $f$, we define the upper and lower right derivatives
> $$D^* f(t)=\limsup\limits_{h\downarrow0}\frac{f(t+h)-f(t)}{h}\tag{1}$$
> $$D_* f(t)=\liminf\limits_{h\downarrow0}\frac{f(t+h)-f(t)}{h}\tag{2}$$
> [...]
> Given a standard Brownian motion $(B(n))_n$, by [Lemma 1.1 (p.2)](https://www.math-berlin.de/images/stories/lecnotes_moerters.pdf) we construct a further Brownian motion $(X(n))_n$ (as stated [there](https://www.math-berlin.de/images/stories/lecnotes_moerters.pdf), $X(n)=\frac{1}{a}B(a^2 n)$). Then:
> $$D^* X(0)\color{red}{\ge}\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{X\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-X(0)}{\frac{1}{n}}\color{red}{\ge}\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}X\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\tag{3}$$ [...]

---

I cannot understand the two $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ inequalities above in $(3)$:

1. **As to the first one**: I would expect, by definition $(1)$, that $D^* X(0)\color{red}{=}\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{X\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-X(0)}{\frac{1}{n}}$ and not that $D^* X(0)\color{red}{\ge}\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{X\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-X(0)}{\frac{1}{n}}$. Why is it that way?
2. **As to the second one**: why does it hold true that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{X\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-X(0)}{\frac{1}{n}}\color{red}{\ge}\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}X\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$? How can one make a comparison between the $\limsup$ of $\frac{X\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-X(0)}{\frac{1}{n}}$ and the $\limsup$ of $\sqrt{n}X\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$?

Comment: For the first inequality, one is taking the limit along a sequence of rational numbers, so one can only expect an inequality rather than an equality.

Comment: Pardon, I am not very familiar with such concepts. First, why do you say that "one is taking the limit along a sequence of rational numbers"? Is $\frac{X\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-X(0)}{\frac{1}{n}}$ rational? Then, why taking the $\lim$ along a sequence of rational numbers leads to an inequality rather than to an equality? @rubikscube09

Comment: $\limsup_{h \downarrow 0} f(h) = \lim_{a \to 0}\sup_{x \in (0,a)}f(x) \geq \lim_{a \to 0}  \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}, \frac{1}{n} \leq a}f \left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = \limsup_{n \to \infty} f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$

Comment: One limit evaluates the function at all points in small balls around $0$, whereas the other evaluates the limit at rational points of the form $f(1/n)$, so the supremum on the right hand side will be smaller than the one the left, because we are taking the supremum over a smaller index set.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Any hint about the second $\color{red}{\text{red }}$inequality? @rubikscube09

Comment: This follows from the fact that $|n X(1/n)| \geq 
|\sqrt{n}X(1/n)|$ - simplify the denominator in the left expression.

Comment: Do you mean $|n X(1/n)| \geq  |\sqrt{n}X(1/n)|$ for $n\ge1$? Anyway, I guess this is enough since we are reasoning about limit (hence, for $n$ sufficiently large), correct? @rubikscube09

Comment: Finally, again as to your answer to the question regarding the first red inequality, when you say that "the supremum on the right hand side will be smaller than the one the left, because we are taking the supremum over a smaller index set.", you mean that the "rationals index set" is a subset of the "reals index set", whence the supremum taken over the "rationals index set" will be smaller than the one taken over the "reals index set", don't you? In general, how can you be sure that $n\in\mathbb{N}$? It is not specified in the text. Couldn'it be that $n\in\mathbb{R}$ instead? @rubikscube09

Comment: when texts use the terminology $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ it always means to take the limit along the sequence of integers, $n = 1,2,3, \cdots $. This is important in probability theory in particular, because probabilities interact nicely with countable objects (countable additivity), and interact poorly with uncountable objects. Thus, many times instead of taking limits along the reals, we take limits along the rationals or integers, and somehow compare them, or show them to be the same as the limit along the reals using topological or numerical (inequality based) arguments.

Comment: OK, thank you a lot. Hence, your answer to this *"when you say that "the supremum on the right hand side will be smaller than the one the left, because we are taking the supremum over a smaller index set.", you mean that the "rationals index set" is a subset of the "reals index set", whence the supremum taken over the "rationals index set" will be smaller than the one taken over the "reals index set", don't you?"* is "yes, I do"? @rubikscube09

Comment: Yes - your interpretation of my comment is correct.

Comment: If you wish, I would be very glad to accept an answer from you consisting of a brief summary of your comments. Thank you! @rubikscube09